# Second exterior power canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171986/why-is-an-alternating-2-form-decomposable-if-and-only-if-its-self-wedge-vanish) question, and the first answer says:

> There is a canonical form: there is a basis $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ of $V$ and a $k$ such that $w=e_1 \wedge e_2 + \cdots + e_{2k−1} \wedge e_{2k}$.

Why is this true? I wasn't able to come up with a proof. My knowledge of exterior algebra is the most basic. If I understand correctly, vectors $e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2}$ form the basis of $\bigwedge^2(V)$, but wouldn't that mean that every $w \in \bigwedge^2(V)$ could be written as $a_1(e_1 \wedge e_2) + a_2(e_1 \wedge e_3) + \cdots$, meaning that not only $e_k \wedge e_{k + 1}$ terms are present, but also $e_k \wedge e_{k + p}$? I'm very confused about this.

Comment: This is a standard result concerning symplectic forms. I don't have reference in English, but I think most advanced linear algebra books would cover this topic.

Comment: (5.3) in [Keith Conrad, *Bilinear forms*](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf) says this in the language of matrices.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thank you for the reference! I already know that for any alternating bilinear form, there is a symplectic basis of the vector space, but I struggle to see the relation between alternating bilinear forms and second exterior power (it's the dual space of the vector space of alternating bilinear forms, right?). I don't understand how to get the statement in question from symplectic basis...

Comment: Writing this up is a pain in the ass. Basically, take a matrix that translates the standard basis into the symplectic basis. Either this matrix or its inverse will send $w$ to $e_1 \wedge e_2 + \cdots + e_{2k-1} \wedge e_{2k}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thank you, but unfortunately I'm still unable to understand. Why does this matrix (or its inverse, which is it?) send $w$ to the representation in question? Would you maybe know the book where I could look this up if expanding this idea is too time-consuming for you at the moment?

Comment: Let $\mathbf{k}$ be your base field, which I assume to be of characteristic $\neq 2$. Consider the map $\phi : \mathbf{k}^{n \times n} \to \wedge^2 \left(\mathbf{k}^n\right)$ that sends each matrix $A = \left(A_{i,j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}$ to the element $\sum_{i, j} A_{i, j} e_i \wedge e_j$ of $\wedge^2 \left(\mathbf{k}^n\right)$ (where the $e_i$ form the standard basis). The restriction of this map $\phi$ to the subspace of all alternating (= skew-symmetric) matrices is an isomorphism. ...

Comment: ... The multiplicative monoid $\mathbf{k}^{n \times n}$ acts both on itself by "pseudo-conjugation" (that is, $W$ sends $A$ to $W A W^T$) and on $\wedge^2\left(\mathbf{k}^n\right)$ directly (i.e., $W$ sends $v \wedge w$ to $Wv \wedge Ww$). Remains to check that $\phi$ is a morphism of $\mathbf{k}^{n \times n}$-modules.